# Como puedo sacar el espacio que deja el body entre dos contenedores, no me deja juntarlos

Tags: css, flexbox

Bueno he estado aprendiendo `flexbox` y lo que me pasa es que cuando le pongo el alto al `body` va bien pero el `footer` no es `sticky`, en cambio, cuando le cambio la dirección de `row` a `column` se arregla el espaciado que hay pero el `footer` igual deja de ser `sticky`.

El código como esta acá cumple con la función de `sticky` `footer` pero no se porque no puedo juntar el menú con el contenedor rojo, el `body` es el morado, como puedo lograr que se junten. y mantener el `sticky` `footer` que funciona con este código.

```css
/*
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
*/
/* 
    Created on : 22-ago-2018, 21:07:39
    Author     : Ricardo
*/

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
/*html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}*/
body {
    background-color: purple;
    height: 100%;
}
.contenedor {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height:100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}


.menu {
    background-color: black;
    height: 25px;
    border: 2px solid yellow;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    
}

.menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    background-color:red;
    border: 2px solid orange;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.imagenes {
    background-color: orange;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    align-self:flex-end;
    border: 2px solid green;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <div class="contenedor"> 
            <nav class="menu">
                <header class="logo"><img src="">LOGO</header>
                <a href="">Inicio</a>
                <a href="">Proyectos</a>
                <a href="">Contacto</a>
                <a href="">Equipo</a>
            </nav>
          
            <section>
                <article>
                <header>Titulo del articulo</header>
                </article>
            </section>
             <div class="imagenes">
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
                 ACA IMAGENES<br>
           
           
                 

            </div>
            <footer>
                <p>ola</p
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

En la pagina en miniatura se ve bien pero veanla en tamaño real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando maquetes, te recomiendo hacerlo así

```
<div class="contenedor">
  <header>
    <nav></nav>
  </header>
  <main>
    <!--content-->
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

Y a la etiqueta `<main>` añadirle el siguiente estilo css:

```
main{
  width: 100%;
  /*El alto de la ventana, menos la altura del menú y del footer*/
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 25px); 
}
```

Lo coloco aquí, con un color diferente de todo lo demás:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100%;
}
.contenedor {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height:100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.menu {
  background-color: black;
  height: 25px; /*altura de menú*/
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}
.menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
main{
  width: 100%;
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 25px);
  background: crimson;
}
section {
  background-color:red;
  border: 2px solid orange;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.imagenes {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
footer {
  align-self:flex-end;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px; /*altura del footer*/
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="contenedor"> 
    <nav class="menu">
      <header class="logo">
        <img src="">LOGO
      </header>
    </nav>
    <main>
      <section>
        <article>
        <header>Titulo del articulo</header>
        </article>
      </section>
      <div class="imagenes">
        ACA IMAGENES<br>
        ACA IMAGENES<br>
        ACA IMAGENES<br>     
      </div>
    </main>
    <footer>
     <p>ola</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: muchas gracias, me diste una solucion sin tener que cambiar el flex-direction. Tengo una duda si me la puedes aclarar porque entonces se producia el error que tenia yo? osea el contenedor main es la solucion? en resumen.

Comment: La solución no es el **main**, de hecho puede cualquier otra etiqueta que agrupe el contenido. El error se da, porque en realidad no se crea ese espacio, es que el alto de las cajas flexibles o de bloque depende de su contenido, es decir, por defecto no se expande para ocupar el espacio restante que es lo que pretendías, sino que se posicionaron al centro y al ser la ventana más alta, una vez que los contenedores alcanzan la altura máxima de su contenido dejan de crecer y expandirse, mostrando el fondo del elemento.

Comment: Ah y te recomiendo mucho leer sobre el **sticky footer** y cómo lograrlo, así como el **align-content: stretch** que en tu caso no funcionaria porque a los elementos le asignas una altura específica, como hiciste con el menú y el footer. Lee esto: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/ y https://escss.blogspot.com/2014/07/sticky-footer-pie-siempre-abajo-css.html.

Comment: en todos los casos que use esta forma de hacer la pagina con flex deberia ocupar  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px - 25px);  para determinar el alto q debe tener entonces en cualquier tipo de contenedor

Comment: Se podría decir que si, que siempre es una buena solución, pero te pase unos enlaces donde hay otras formas de lograrlo con ese mismo html y es por ejemplo usar **css grid** ahora también te puedes ayudar con las variables css y crear algo como **.contenedor_principal { calc( 100vh - var(--altura_encabezado) - var(--altura-footer)) }** aunque depende del contenido que estas diseñado, por ejemplo en una web app es algo inevitable, pero en un sitio web donde el contenido de una página no sobrepasa el **"fold"** ese contenido no debería de estar por separado.